# jqPlot show image on button click

Tags: javascript, image, button, charts, jqplot

I am using jqPlot to display some charts also with a button to enable the chart to be saved to an image.

Can I please have some help to modify the code so that rather than have a button, the image is shown when the chart is clicked on.

Here is my code:

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var cosPoints = []; 
for (var i=0; i<2*Math.PI; i+=0.1){ 
 cosPoints.push([i, Math.cos(i)]); 
} 
var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [cosPoints], {  
  series:[{showMarker:false}],
  axes:{
    xaxis:{
      label:'Angle (radians)'
    },
    yaxis:{
      label:'Cosine'
    }
  }
});

if (!$.jqplot.use_excanvas) {
var outerDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
var header = $(document.createElement('div'));
var div = $(document.createElement('div'));

outerDiv.append(header);
outerDiv.append(div);

outerDiv.addClass('jqplot-image-container');
header.addClass('jqplot-image-container-header');
div.addClass('jqplot-image-container-content');

header.html('Right Click to Save Image As...');

var close = $(document.createElement('a'));
close.addClass('jqplot-image-container-close');
close.html('Close');
close.attr('href', '#');
close.click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div.jqplot-image-container').hide(500);
})
header.append(close);

$('#chart1').after(outerDiv);
outerDiv.hide();

outerDiv = header = div = close = null;

var btn = $(document.createElement('button'));
btn.text('View Plot Image');
btn.addClass('jqplot-image-button');
btn.bind('click', {chart: $('#chart1')}, function(evt) {
    var imgelem = evt.data.chart.jqplotToImageElem();
    var div = $(this).nextAll('div.jqplot-image-container').first();
    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').empty();
    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').append(imgelem);
    div.show(500);
    div = null;
});

$('#chart1').after(btn);
btn.after('<br />');
btn = null;
}  
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

For multiple charts only one image is shown. What do I need to do with this code to be able to show more than one chart? Also, each chart is in a different div:

```
$('#chart1').after(outerDiv);
outerDiv.hide();

outerDiv = header = div = close = null;
```

**UPDATE2**

For some reason, none of my charts are now displaying. I am guessing that there is a simple error in my code. Can I please have some help on what I have done wrong? Also, the charts are called 'FinancialsLineGraph' and 'SalesMonthVsBudgetLineGraph'.

Here is my full code:

```
if (!$.jqplot.use_excanvas) {
var charts = ['#FinancialsLineGraph', '#SalesMonthVsBudgetLineGraph'];

$.each(charts, function(index, value) {
    (function(chartId) {
var outerDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
var header = $(document.createElement('div'));
var div = $(document.createElement('div'));

outerDiv.append(header);
outerDiv.append(div);

outerDiv.addClass('jqplot-image-container');

header.addClass('jqplot-image-container-header');
div.addClass('jqplot-image-container-content');

header.html('Right Click to Save Image As...');

var close = $(document.createElement('a'));
close.addClass('jqplot-image-container-close');
close.html('Close');
close.attr('href', '#');
close.click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div.jqplot-image-container').hide(500);
})
header.append(close);

$(chartId).after(outerDiv);
outerDiv.hide();

outerDiv = header = div = close = null;

    })(value);
});
```

**UPDATE**

I have found a working solution for each individual chart. Here is my code:

```
    $('#FinancialsLineGraph').bind('jqplotClick', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {                    
 var outerDiv = $(document.createElement('div'));
var header = $(document.createElement('div'));
var div = $(document.createElement('div'));

outerDiv.append(header);
outerDiv.append(div);

outerDiv.addClass('jqplot-image-container');
header.addClass('jqplot-image-container-header');
div.addClass('jqplot-image-container-content');

header.html('Right Click to Save Image As...');

var close = $(document.createElement('a'));
close.addClass('jqplot-image-container-close');
close.html('Close');
close.attr('href', '#');
close.click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div.jqplot-image-container').hide(500);
})
header.append(close);

$('#FinancialsLineGraph').after(outerDiv);
outerDiv.hide();   

outerDiv = header = div = close = null;  

var imgelem = $('#FinancialsLineGraph').jqplotToImageElem();
var div = $(this).nextAll('div.jqplot-image-container').first();
div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').empty();
div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').append(imgelem);
div.show(500);
div = null;

});
```

Comment: You are missing a `}` from the end of the updated code.

Comment: I have the charts displaying. The 'if (!$.jqplot.use_excanvas) {' code executes when the page loads, but not on any click events on the chart. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this block of code:

```
var btn = $(document.createElement('button'));
btn.text('View Plot Image');
btn.addClass('jqplot-image-button');
btn.bind('click', {chart: $('#chart1')}, function(evt) {
    var imgelem = evt.data.chart.jqplotToImageElem();
    var div = $(this).nextAll('div.jqplot-image-container').first();
    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').empty();
    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').append(imgelem);
    div.show(500);
    div = null;
});

$('#chart1').after(btn);
btn.after('<br />');
btn = null;
```

With this one:

```
$('#chart1').bind('jqplotClick', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {                
    var imgelem = $('#chart1').jqplotToImageElem();
    var div = $(this).nextAll('div.jqplot-image-container').first();
    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').empty();
    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').append(imgelem);
    div.show(500);
    div = null;
});
```

**Edit:**

To get that code working for multiple plots you could try something like this:

```
if (!$.jqplot.use_excanvas) {
    var charts = ['#chart1', '#chart2', '#chart3'];

    $.each(charts, function(index, value) {
        (function(chartId) {
            //The code that you currently have in the if-block.

        })(value);
    });
}
```

You will then need to replace any occurrence of `'#chart1'` within the `$each` with `chartId`.

**Edit 2:**

I think your full code is missing the part where the plot event is wired up.

Where you currently have:

```
outerDiv = header = div = close = null;
```

Add this right after it:

```
$(chartId).bind('jqplotClick', function(ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {                
    var imgelem = $(chartId).jqplotToImageElem();
    var div = $(this).nextAll('div.jqplot-image-container').first();
    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').empty();
    div.children('div.jqplot-image-container-content').append(imgelem);
    div.show(500);
    div = null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That works well. However, if I have 3 Charts on a page, called  chart1, chart2, chart3, can I please have some help to get the image displayed to work for each graph?

Comment: @user2023359 Try this one.

Comment: @user2023359 Check my comment to the question. I think you are missing a curly brace at the end.

Comment: Thanks Nick_w for your help. I have found a working solution and have placed it in the original post.